# Can cutting electrical steel alter its magnetic properties?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, core

Please forgive me in advance if this question is not appropriate here. If you think so - let me know and I'll take it down. However I am really hoping someone can share their thoughts!

I want to make an experimental transformer using standard, off-the-shelf U I laminated electrical steel sheets.  As a part of the experiment,  I need to form a gap in the core of a certain specific shape. I want to cut the sheets myself, but I am just wondering if cutting the sheets will stress the electrical steel so that its magnetic properties might be changed, reducing the efficiency of the transformer. Can anyone comment on this?

I was planning on cutting the sheet (0.5mm) with a hacksaw. Very low tech I know, but I don't have the money to get a custom core made...bad idea?

Comment: As long as your not heating the metal i don't see why you would change its properties. For cutting it i would recommend snips instead of a hack saw. It is recommended to have at least 2 teeth inside your work when using a hacksaw. With 0.5mm material that is difficult.

Comment: An alternative to a hacksaw would be a "sheet metal nibbler".  A good one can cut clean sharp edges without deforming the sheet and with zero dust particles.  Get the type that cuts out a tiny square of metal by pulling it through the sheet.  You'll have fore-arms like Popeye afterwards. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper heat treatment can change the magnetic properties of the steel yes.

However manually forming each sheet will not produce a great product. A better solution may be to stack-and-mill.

That is, stack and fix your sheets to the thickness you require, and then mill the stack, or have some-one mill it, to your desired dimensions.

The milling process can be done using a coolant to ensure heat introduced is minimized and your resulting core will be much more uniform.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes and no:

Of course, cutting steel is going to produce a lot of heat. Heating changes the metal structure and will alter the properties.

But: with a slow hacksaw, that effect is probably not really relevant at all.

What I'd worry much more about is that you still need to stack multiple of these sheets, and you will

- break the lamination close to your cut, leading to stray currents across the sheets, which might reduce efficiency
- slightly bend, wave the sheets, so that they won't perfectly stack, which will reduce efficiency

So, I don't think the hacksaw is the optimal tool here; I don't know where you are, but it's often pretty easy to find metal workshops in any city, and many of those have CNC cutters, and CNC drills. They aren't really expensive, and you'll save yourself a lot of pain and get better results if you ask them to cut things for you.

It's generally a good idea to show up in person with your stock U's, and explain what you need to happen, and ask whether you can watch while they work on your metal. Most craftspeople are kind of proud of what they do, and you might learn a lot about handling the metal the way they do it professionally – and that might save you a lot of headache, metal dust, finger damage and cost later on :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler way of doing that. You can put a sheet of foil over the entire U-I joint surface. Instead making a 0.5mm space, that would be very difficult to trim the saw to match exact cutting length, you can put a 0.25mm PE sheet on both sides. Technically the gap will be the same 2 x 0.25mm = 0.5mm, also the characteristics of new transformer core.